# Java loop, need suggestion for code simplification..

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, joptionpane

I am just practicing Java as a beginner. So here is the question:
Suppose you save $100 each month into a savings account with the annual interest rate 5%. Thus, the monthly interest rate is 0.00417. After the first month, the value in the account becomes 100 * (1 + 0.00417) = 100.417 and the second month will be (100 + firstMonthValue) * 1.00417, and then goes on like so every month. So here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class vinalcialApplication {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String monthlySaving = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the monthly savings");
        double monthsaving = Double.parseDouble(monthlySaving);
        //define monthly rate
        double monthlyrate = 1.00417;
        double totalrate = monthlyrate + 0.00417;
        double firstMonthValue = monthsaving * (totalrate);
    double secondMonthValue = (firstMonthValue + 100)*(monthlyrate);
    double thridMonthValue = (secondMonthValue + 100) * (monthlyrate);

     .........
    System.out.print("After the sixth month, the account value is " sixthMonthValue);
}
```

}

I mean the code works but it is too much code to write.. I am sure I can use a loop or if statement to do this but haven't figured a way to do it yet.. can you please help?
Thank you.

Comment: *"can you please help?"*  Can you please *try* using a loop before asking?

Comment: I tried, it didn't work, that is why I came here.. next time I will attach the code to it... sorry

Comment: *"next time I will attach the code to it"*  Your [question can be edited](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16291887/edit) right now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class vinalcialApplication {
public static void main(String args[]){
    String monthlySaving = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the monthly savings");
    double monthsaving = Double.parseDouble(monthlySaving);
    //define monthly rate
    double monthlyrate = 1.00417;
    double totalrate = monthlyrate + 0.00417;
    double value = monthsaving * (totalrate);
    for(int i = 1; i<6;i++) {
        value = (value + 100)*(monthlyrate);
    }
    System.out.print("After the sixth month, the account value is " value);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! it helped me to find out where I have done wrong in the looping code.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, this is called compound interest.

There is a mathematical formula to achieve what you wanted without looping.

Here is the formula from wikipedia

[image]

Where,
A = future value, P = principal amount (initial investment),r = annual nominal interest, rate, n = number of times the interest is compounded per year,t = number of years

Hope this helps you in solving what you wanted. I can give you sample code, but I think it is fairly easy to convert this formula to java statement. Let us know if you need any more info.

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest

Comment: Thank you! I should have thought of this formula, very helpful, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The maths is probably wrong, but the basic concept is sound.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double monthsaving = 100;
    double monthlyrate = 1.00417;

    double savings = 0;
    // Loop for six months...
    for (int index = 0; index < 6; index++) {
        savings += monthsaving * monthlyrate;
        System.out.println(index + ":" + savings);
    }
    System.out.println(savings);
}
```

Take a closer look at [Control Flow Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/flow.html), paying attaching with `while`, `do-while` and `for` statements